# The easiest way to extend Linux version in Yocto

Tags: linux, kernel, yocto, bitbake

I'm trying to extend Linux version in my project on a tag from git repository. I manged to pass tag value to Linux-*.bb and looking for the best solution to add it to kernel version so I can see it in /etc/kernel-version file and as an output after typing `"uname -r" e.g: 3..11.67-my-tag`.

I know that there is something like LINUX_KERNEL_EXTENSION but I didn't mange to make it working.

What is the easiest way to do it and how can I test it without flashing my board?

Thanks,

Comment: In latest Yocto version, it is named [LINUX_VERSION_EXTENSION](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-LINUX_VERSION_EXTENSION), and it is related to kernel recipe. We need to know which virtual/kernel do you use? Basically you will need to create a bbappend file, and modify that variable in it. Be careful as it can be overrided in an other way, check this [thread](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Linux/Unable-to-set-kernel-local-version/td-p/813004). I'm not sure what you mean by "without flashing my board"? You will need to install the new kernel.

Answer (score 2):

There is a dedicated configuration option, name `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION`, which can be found under `General Setup -> Local version - append to kernel release`. You can add it by simply using `bitbake -c menuconfig` or directly adding following lines in your kernel configuration file:

```
CONFIG_LOCALVERSION="+mycustomboard"
CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO=y
```

If you need to add your tag value as extension, you have to add these following lines in your kernel recipe:

```
LOCALVERSION = "+mycustomboard-${LINUX_VERSION_EXTENSION}"
LINUX_VERSION_EXTENSION = "1.2.3"
```

In that way, `uname -r` output shall contain `+mycustomboard-1.2.3` as you expect.